# SEO impact of hundreds of internal links for browsing reports by alphabet

Tags: seo, google, links

On my website, I have finance related research reports of around 1000 companies. The template is common. Already I have a search box to help visitors locate a firm's report. But I feel the users will benefit more if I give quick links to all the 1000 reports categorized by alphabets.

For example, the first page will have quick links to reports of all firm's starting with A, the second page for B and so on. Will doing this hurt SEO? Will Google suspect any manipulation? If so, is there some attribute like "no-follow" that will help?

Comment: I managed a similar navigation scheme years ago with millions of pages. Today it is important to have a link to all of your pages otherwise they can be dropped from the index, however there are no good ways of doing so except for what you are suggesting. You may want to consider marking these pages noindex. Google will follow the links, but what is the long term effect? I am not sure. Things have changed recently. I will up vote your question to see if we can get you more attention. Push comes to shove you can offer a bounty. Cheers!!

Answer (score 2):

Do you already have a page with all the reports? Or you have a page with a search box for searching the reports?

Instead of creating new pages that each contain a list of report-links based on their first letter, you can enhance your search functionality on the page you already have or slightly re-structure it.

What I have in mind, is to have all the report-links appear in one page (the one you already have), categorized alphabetically based on their first letter. Each link will direct to the report-specific page and each report-specific page will have a link directing back to the main report-links page.

That way you get the following benefits:

1.) You enhance the authority of the page you already have.

2.) You don't need to create hundreds of new pages, you use the links you already have and just categorize them in one page.

If you don't have a page for listing all the links and just have a search box (hence my initial question), consider creating a dedicated page for listing links to the reports. It will still be easier (and better) to do and maintain than creating many new pages, both programming and SEO wise.

Comment: I just build a dedicated page for listing links (split into about 10 pages 1-10). Splitting helps users to locate a report with ease. My question however is such implementation harmful from google point of view?

Comment: @Kannan which is the case, a single page with 10 sub-pages in it or 10 separate pages (each with its own url)? If it is the first, you should be ok assuming you created internal links, canonical tags etc.